# Excel: What can cause manual calculation / F9 to stop recalculating?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

What can cause manual calculation/<kbd>F9</kbd> to stop recalculating some cells properly in Excel 2010 ?

I've Googled this problem and ruled out all the explanations I can find:

- Calculation settings are set to automatic.
- Formulas/Calculation Options for the tab is set to automatic.
- Manually recalculating doesn't work.
- Calculate in VBA doesn't do it.
- It's not a circular reference or numbers stored as text issue.

Normally calculating manually with <kbd>F9</kbd> or switching calculation to automatic works as expected, but sometimes I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate certain cells. That works as a short term workaround, but I need to fix the problem going forward to calculate normally. I've only ever seen the issue happen in specific cells in spreadsheets sent to me by one person. I've been unable to recreate the issue or figure out what is causing it.

I hope this is ok to ask here, I tried on StackOverflow and was told it was a question for SuperUser.

Comment: Any similarities in the cells it happens to?

Comment: I've only found it in one portion of one worksheet.  Specifically, it's just the iferror formula referencing cells on the same worksheet which seem to be recalculating normally.

Comment: What if you copy that sheet to another workbook? Does it still happen?

Comment: Thanks.  Copying the tab to a new workbook and manually calculating seems to calculate as expected.

Comment: I'd imagine either the book is corrupted or there's some VBA somewhere in the book or sheets module.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see any VBA that would account for that.  Any idea how that type of corruption would happen, or how to avoid it?

Comment: I don't know how it would happen, maybe a corrupted office

Comment: " corruption would happen".. in many ways.. eg.. disk error (sudden usb eject/hdd bad sector) while saving.. corrupted memory while loading.. and opening it in a very different excel.. then saving it.. or excel may crash (once..) then automatically recovers the file.. but the recovery includes corrupted bit/part. || Since saving it in new file solves it.. then it is a prove that the 'base' excel file is problematic, not the formula.

Answer (score 1):

A. If you use Macro functions or some specific CELL function, they do not recalculate when you use F9. That is per user manual.

B. If you do *any* other action during the calculation, it stops. This includes cursor-down and such things. Basically, any key you press (and any button you click) stops the recalculation; including ALT-TAB to switch windows.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have your funtion lock enabled by accident.
Try pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and try <kbd>F9</kbd> again. It should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem the answers on the usual forums were worthless.  In the end I discovered that somehow the F9 key had been disabled.  It had nothing to do with macros, the formulas, interrupting during the calculation, the cell format, manual/auto update setting, reference to other files, or any of the other expert-offered nonexplanations. Eventually I found out how to re-enable F9.    The microsoft forum referred to a "function lock" key above the backspace on my keyboard... but I have no such key.  However it is very simple to unlock F9, by the simultaneous pressing three keys on your keyboard.  This is a deeply hidden secret that the responders at the locked **answers.microsoft.com** forum do not want revealed, so I will not reveal it here.

Comment: This is a joke right? The key sequence in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1546286/399707) states that the lock is `Fn+Esc+F9`... so why the secrecy?

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the Cell Format for the cell containing the formula that won't calculate to ensure it is NOT set to "Text". If it is, change it to *General*.

[image: Cell format value in Ribbon]

Then edit the cell and exit the cell. The formula should now resolve.

I recently encountered the same issue and this seems to happen only for cells of format *Text*. When it does occur, I haven't found a way for the formula to resolve without editing and exiting the cell. Copying and pasting the cell, whether pasting Formula, Format, or even Value still produces the unresolved formula.

Comment: A text is not a formula, and is not supposed to be calculated. Even if it looks like a formula.

Comment: @Aganju - that is my point. If the format is set to Text, the OP's described symptoms would occur. I edited my post to make it clearer to change Format from Text to General.

Comment: no, if it is set to 'Text', everything would look exactly as he types (so `4` would look `4` and not `4.000000`), and the numbers could not be used for formulas.